# SQL - Stored Proc to Update table from Table Variable

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a stored procedure which inserts records into a table using values from my table variable. (The table variable is sent to SQL from ASP.NET) It works perfect and looks like this...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_SaveResponses 
(
@TableVariable SaveResponsesTableType READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tbl_Responses
(
assessmentid, questionid, answerid
)
SELECT assessmentid, questionid, answerid
FROM @TableVariable
END
```

The above inserts one record into tbl_Responses for every row in @TableVariable.

**The Problem**
Instead of INSERT, I would like to perform an UPDATE, but I can't get the syntax right.

Thanks for any help...!

**UPDATE**
With some helpful hints, I was able to resolve this below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ipr1010 and @cob666 whose answers led me in the right direction... Here is the solution.

```
UPDATE tbl_Responses SET answerid = T1.answerid
FROM @TableVariable T1
WHERE tbl_Responses.assessmentid = T1.assessmentid AND tbl_Responses.questionid = T1.questionid
```

Naming @TableVariable T1 resolved the "must declare scalar variable..." issue. 
I also needed to update my WHERE clause or all values were updated with the first value in @TableVariable.

I wish I could vote you guys up but apparently my street cred is too weak!

Answer (score 3):

You could try this (I haven't tested it) -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_SaveResponses 
(
@TableVariable SaveResponsesTableType READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE tbl_Responses set questionid = @TableVariable.questionid
FROM @TableVariable
WHERE @TableVariable.assessmentid = tbl_Response.assessmentid 
END
```

Comment: this looks great but @TableVariable.questionid and @TableVariable.assessmentid throw errors (must declare scalar variable @TableVariable). ???

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the join is between the table variable and the table that needs to be updated:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_SaveResponses 
(
@TableVariable SaveResponsesTableType READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE 
        tbl_Responses 
    SET 
        questionid = @TableVariable.questionid
    FROM 
        @TableVariable T1
        JOIN tbl_Responses T2 ON T1.assessmentid = T2.assessmentID
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but @TableVariable.questionid throws an error (must declare scalar variable @TableVariable). Any ideas? Thx!